# c# Linq: Replace empty string with some value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list as:

```
var myList = lookuplist;

//where lookupList
       Count = 2
          [0]: "36"
          [1]: ""
```

Above list is basically being populated by parsing from my excel file. Sorry the code before this is not relevant so not showing that.

My issue is I want to update the empty string with a space. So I tried the code below:

```
myList .Where(w => w.Length == 0).Select(y=>y = "  ").ToList();
```

But it does not changes anything.

Am I missing something here. I can use a forach to loop through my list but I want to use linq.

Sorry if this is trivial.

Comment: why you think that assign local variable will change something in the collection?

Comment: Yes that wont work but even not assigning it and modifying the lookuplist directly it doesnt work

Comment: no your code is like `string t = "aa"; string y = t; y = " ";` ... gues what ... it is still "aa"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to assign the updated list back to the original variable.  You can do something like this:

```
myList = myList.Select(y => string.IsNullOrEmpty(y) ? " " : y).ToList();
```